# Can Daedalus be used to query the blockchain, like a passive node?

Tags: daedalus, cardano-cli, cardano-node

Daedalus is a full node wallet application, but can I use the full node to query the ledger?

Answer (score 16):

Daedalus runs its own instance of `cardano-node` under the hood, so by installing and using `cardano-cli`, one can connect to this node and interact with the blockchain directly.

1. Start Daedalus, and wait until it reaches the wallet home screen; the `cardano-node.socket` file is only made available after the `cardano-node` has started fully.
2. Use `cardano-cli`: [[Documentation](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node#cardano-cli)]

#### Ubuntu Example (Bash)

```
export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/home/$USER/.local/share/Daedalus/mainnet/cardano-node.socket
cardano-cli query tip --mainnet
```

#### MacOS Example

```
export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=~/Library/Application\ Support/Daedalus\ Mainnet/cardano-node.socket
cardano-cli query tip --mainnet
```

#### Windows Example (PowerShell)

On Windows, a socket file isn't used, instead we specify the pipe used, which has a different name every time Daedalus runs.

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Daedalus Mainnet"
$ENV:CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH = (Get-ChildItem \\.\pipe\ | Where-Object {$_.name -like "cardano-node*"}).FullName
.\cardano-cli.exe query tip --mainnet
```

Comment: Would be nice to have Windows and MacOS examples too, at least the default socket paths

Comment: Ah I forgot how awkward it was to get the Windows named pipe :D

Comment: @soccer193 Trying it via PowerShell doesn't appear to work. Deadalus is running, node fully sync'd.  "Shelley command failed: query tip  Error: Error while looking up environment variable: CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH  Error: "CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH""  

If I run:

    Get-ChildItem \\.\pipe\ | Where-Object {$_.name -like "cardano-node-mainnet*"}    

It returns nothing.  Currently using PowerShell 7.1.3

Comment: Hey @ChadCarter, left you a response in the 'Cardano' chat room on the right of this page.

Comment: @soccer193 I posted a response in the chat the other day. If you have any ideas on where the socket path should be in Windows, I'd love to know.

Comment: I'm no powershell expert. It seems simply calling Get-ChildItem \\.\pipe\ doesn't return anything related to cardano.  However, when I downloaded the sysinternals PipeList and ran the 64bit version ( https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PipeList.zip ) I saw a ton more named pipe entries including one called "cardano-node-mainnet.18404.5".  So I ran $ENV:CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH = "\\.\pipe\cardano-node-mainnet.18404.5"      followed by the cli query line and got the result I was after.  What can we do to get PS to see it?

Comment: `$env:CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH = [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\\pipe\\") | where { $_ -like "*cardano-node*" }`

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use **standard Windows CMD** (instead of PowerShell) we first need to get the PID of the right "Daedalus Mainnet" process (there are multiple) eg 12345, then set CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH eg:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Daedalus Mainnet"
set CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=\\.\pipe\cardano-node-mainnet.12345.0
```

(Swap the 12345 with your PID value, see below. You might need to change the .0 too)

Then run your cardano-cli commands eg

```
cardano-cli query tip --mainnet
```

This should then work until you restart Daedalus.

Note: make sure Daedalus is fully synced before running cardano-cli

*To get the PID manually via Task manager:*

I see 4 processes named "Daedalus Mainnet" under the Processes tab in Windows11. Select the one with extra details after the name eg "(4.8.0#23001)" and right-click "Go To Details", note the PID eg 12345.

*To get the PID via PowerShell, run:*

```
(Get-ChildItem \\.\pipe\ | Where-Object {$_.name -like "cardano-node*"}).FullName
```

*(Thanks to soccer193 and Tend for this PS snippet)*