# Is it possible to specify a Windows named pipe for Daedalus?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, daedalus

I'm on a Windows machine and would like to use `cardano-cli` to interact with the Cardano network. I have Daedalus running which is running an instance of `cardano-node`. In order for the CLI to find the node, I have to specify the `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH` environment variable to point to the named Windows pipe (for example, `\\.\pipe\cardano-node-mainnet.15992.0`).

The problem is that every time Daedalus is closed and re-opened, it will use a different named pipe. Therefore, I need to update the `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH` each time.

Is there a way to specify the Windows named pipe for Daedalus such that it would be static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to configure the pipe name used by Daedalus.

But you could use powershell to find it. Something like:

```
$Env:CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH = "\\.\pipe\cardano-node-mainnet.$( (Get-Process -Name daedalus).Id ).0"
```

Comment: Here is a similar question with extra details: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/287/can-daedalus-be-used-to-query-the-blockchain-like-a-passive-node/7398